# How to enabled CCK modules in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6

I am new to Drupal and I wan to built shopping cart on Drupal-6. I am following **Packtpub.Drupal.Ecommerce.with.Ubercart.2.x.Mar.2010**. I have downloaded all required modules.

1. FileField
2. ImageField
3. ImageAPI and ImageAPI GD2
4. ImageCache
5. Thickbox
6. Google Analytics
7. Views
   and after unzip them paste them to **sites/all/modules folder** but to make them enable when I go to **http://mysite/admin/build/modules** their check boxes were disabled (not to be check able)
   [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some more modules, like Content and Getid3. When it says "Depends on: XXX (missing)" that means you need to get that one too.